# Rails Puma server incredibly slow page rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, puma

Recently, my puma server on my ec2 ubuntu instance has been very very slow (>100 sec page load times).

[image: pumaslow]

In the image above you'll see all layers of the rendering stack load 100X slower than they should. I did notice it became slower and slower over time, starting two days ago.

I have the same exact code on a staging site and the server is fine. I've tried restarting, stopping/starting puma, the instance itself, and even gotten AWS support to look and see if any anomalies are occurring within the instance. All negative. RAM and CPU usage is half of capacity, instance looks otherwise healthy. Running fine locally as well.

Has anyone encountered something like this and might know of a cause?

Comment: My money is on that you have multiple n+1 query issues or are not limiting/paginating your queries. That will cause the view to hang while it takes n+1 trips to the database - memory and CPU will be normal but it takes forever. Its also pretty consistent with that the issue builds over time as your database gets larger. There plenty of tutorials and books even about dealing with Rails performance issues and tools like Bullit.

Comment: In generalthis type of question is not a good fit for stackoverflow and it will very likely be closed - "has anybody had the same issue?" is not a practical programming question that can be answered in few paragraphs and we can't actually give you an authoritive answer as what you need to do is further investigation to find the actual cause.